# Understanding Android terminologies

Tags: rom, stock-android

I am a Android greenhorn, and seems like there are a lot of jargon that float around.
Example:

```
Android OS
Android Kernel
Rooting
Recovery
Partition
ROM
Boot locked
BIOS
SIM Locked
stock android
```

etc.

Could any one point me to resource(s) that would clarify these core concepts to me?
I am not looking for easy answers; but rather I need right approach to read and understand these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

1. Android OS is self explained. It's the Android Operating System itself and it's based on Linux.
2. Android Kernel, you should read kernel in general from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)
3. Rooting, is the method to obtain superuser access rights to the OS. Please read here for more info http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser
4. Recovery is a piece of software that can help you flash files or recover from software damage
5. Partition you should look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning
6. Boot(loader) Locked. Bootloader itself is a piece of software that loads the OS after the completion of some power-on tests that the device performs. If the bootloader is locked you cannot change ROM.
7. BIOS Please refere here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS
8. SIM Locked, That means that you entered the PIN of your SIM, three times wrong and the SIM Locked and cannot pefrom calls.
9. Stock Android is the Android as it is released in the AOSP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#AOSP

Your question is very low level and you could get answer, faster and with more contex, using the Google or Wikipedia as am refering to, it too.

You can find some terminologies here http://techpp.com/2011/10/07/understand-the-basic-android-terminologies/ and here http://www.techverse.net/basic-android-root-terminology-for-beginners/ . You should of course watch out for xda-developers forum where you can find very usefull stuff. There is a whole guide with Terms, Slands and Definitions here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1466228 .